# Custom Cursor CSS not working on certain parts of the webpage

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

I am trying to personalize the cursor of my webpage and managed to do so. However, there seem to be certain (random?) parts of the page where the cursor appears as the default version and not as the personalized cursor I had set. Does anyone know how I can resolve this? I added a  element in my HTML document to set the background picture of my site and also used it to set the cursor for the entire body of the page. In my CSS file, I also specified that all links should be my personalized cursor (for some reason it otherwise did not show the personalized cursor on the links).

Here is part of my code in case that is helpful:

```
<style>
body {
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
cursor: url("speakercursor3.png"), auto;
}
</style>
```

And this code in the CSS file:
`a { cursor: url("speakercursor3.png"), auto;}`

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle sample including your image and reproducing your case. There are certain size limitations on cursors, depending on browsers, you can find details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property#limitations. Here's a fiddle reproducing size limitation: https://jsfiddle.net/taq85916/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wpz0rhe6/11/ I am not sure if this is what you wanted since I have never used jsfiddle (sorry again very new to the game). I had to change my cursor image to the one you sent in the suggestion as mine is not available online. The customized cursor is not appearing on the last 2 links on jsfiddle but it dies on my website (i am assuming it is the size of the cursor image). The other places where the cursor is not working is the same as on my page tho. I already tried limiting the size ti 30x30 px but nothing changed sadly. Thank you so so much for all your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers manage your cursor visibility outside of your `<body>` tag. On this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ctf8Lqwn/8/) sample you can see that when you are outside of the blue borders, your cursor will default. Browser will also default your cursor when you are too close to the edges, or in some cases if your cursor goes outside of your browser, it will default. You can observe all in the sample. In your specific case you need to position your elements in a different way or give your body enough height so your elements are contained within it. Latter is not ideal but for PoC here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2fr371kt/).

Comment: This worked - thank you so much!! Made my day :))

Answer (score 2):

So a few things you should check are the elements that are causing issues, check the CSS for those specific elements to make sure they don't have a cursor value set to them.

you can check this by inspecting the elements.  if you are positive that it is not CSS causing the problems, then u could also try js.

Using js would be better in my opinion as u can make the cursor change more dynamically.

**JQUERY CURSOR**

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){

    $('.cursor').css('top', e.pageY);
    
    $('.cursor').css('left', e.pageX);
    
    $("a").mouseenter(function() {
    
        $(".cursor").addClass("link");
    
    });
    
    $("a").mouseleave(function() {
    
        $(".cursor").removeClass("link");
    
    });
    
    $("button").mouseenter(function() {
    
        $(".cursor").addClass("button");
    
    });
    
    $("button").mouseleave(function() {
    
        $(".cursor").removeClass("button");
    
    });
    
});
```

```css
/* mouse cursor */

.cursor {
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
background: #000;
border: solid 2px white;
border-radius: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 100000; /* this is to make sure this is the top most element make this bigger if the cursor is going under other elements */
transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* this is to center the mouse cursor */
cursor: none; /* this is to hide the default cursor */
pointer-events: none; /* this is to make it so that the cursor can still interact with elements */
transition-duration: 000ms;
}

/* hide default cursor everywhere */

* {
cursor: none;
}

.link {
border-color: #5f5;

}

.button {
border-color: #ff5555;
}

body {
overflow-x: hidden; /* this is so that if the cursor is on the edge of the page, it will not axpand the body */ 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cursor"></div>

<a href="">LINK</a>

<button>CLICK</button>
```